# Regex: Why does /^((\d|-){5,10})/ match '20866 United States' with a match group of 6?

Tags: regex

I was attempting to write a regex for certain zipcodes and noticed this oddity.

Using `/^((\d|-){5,10})/` on `'20866 United States'` yields the match groups:

1) 20866

2) 6

I don't understand the second match. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you get this result? What language?

Comment: because you have a grouping inside too.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr is correct because you are capturing 2 groups. Why not just use `/[\d-]{5,10}/` no need for groups and this will match fine.

Answer (score 6):

`(\d|-)` is also a group, and when you have a group that repeats, the last repetition is usually the one that’s captured. (Some engines can capture all of them, too.)

You can make it non-capturing:

```
(?:\d|-){5,10}
```

or avoid the group altogether:

```
[\d-]{5,10}
```